# Can't get alchemy.js graph visualisation to show panel, zoom or search

Tags: d3.js, alchemy.js

The alchemy.js lib is create and provides good abstraction for graph layouts. I can't seem to get the application example that has a panel, allows searching and filtering. Zooming does not work either. 
Here are the config values:

```
var config = {
dataSource: team,                      
cluster: true,
nodeCaption: "firstName",
rootNodeRadius: 30,      
nodeCaptionsOnByDefault: true,
directedEdges:true,
showControlDash: true,
showStats: true,
nodeStats: true,
showFilters: true,
nodeFilters: true,
captionToggle: true,
edgesToggle: true,
nodesToggle: true,
toggleRootNotes: false,
search: true,
zoomControls: true
};
```

Here is the code that is not working:
https://jsfiddle.net/aneesha/mpa6sbsb/6/

Comment: Yep. Doesn't work for me either. Did you ever figure anything out?

Answer (score 2):

So... I dug around and they seem to have left toggleControlDash out of Alchemy.prototype.interactions in the last couple of versions. I went back to their 0.3.1 version, copy/pasted the function into the new alchemy.js file, and now it works.

I'm pretty sure the examples are all built on different versions. I've found some other things that don't work too, I'm just going to go in and fix them on my own. If you're still looking for help on this, let me know :)

Comment: Do you have this code - I just got the latest version and it is still missing panning / zooming.  Thanks!